# Error - flatten the query result - Cannot read property 'flattenQueryResult' of undefined

Tags: lightning

I try to flatten the query result, But it always gives me the error. Here is my Array
**responseValue.listAll**:[image]

My lightning controller:

```
var listAfterFlatten = [];
            responseValue.listAll.forEach(function (course) {
                console.log("Here is result", course);
                var flattened = this.flattenQueryResult(course);
                listAfterFlatten.push(flattened);

            });
            component.set("v.coursesList", listAfterFlatten);
```

But when I check the console, it gives me the list what I want. 
[image]
Here is my **flattenQueryResult** :

```
flattenQueryResult :function(data) {
        var result = {};
        function recurse (cur, prop) {
            if (Object(cur) !== cur) {
                result[prop] = cur;
            } else if (Array.isArray(cur)) {
                for(var i=0, l=cur.length; i<l; i++)
                    recurse(cur[i], prop + "[" + i + "]");
                if (l == 0)
                    result[prop] = [];
            } else {
                var isEmpty = true;
                for (var p in cur) {
                    isEmpty = false;
                    recurse(cur[p], prop ? prop+"."+p : p);
                }
                if (isEmpty && prop)
                    result[prop] = {};
            }
        }
        recurse(data, "");
        return result;
    }
```

I don't know why it's undefined. Could someone helps me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the error is "Cannot read property 'flattenQueryResult' of undefined" that simply means that JavaScript can't find a function called 'flattenQueryResult'. If you put your 'flattenQueryResult' function in the JavaScript helper you can call it by writing:

var flattened = helper.flattenQueryResult(course);

EDIT

Inside the anonymous function passed as argument to the forEach function the this keyword doesn't refer to the helper, the context is different. 
You can try something like this:

```
        var myFlattenFunction = this.flattenQueryResult;
        var listAfterFlatten = [];
        responseValue.listAll.forEach(function (course) {
            console.log("Here is result", course);
            var flattened = myFlattenFunction(course);
            listAfterFlatten.push(flattened);

        });
        component.set("v.coursesList", listAfterFlatten);
```

Or you can pass the helper object in the argument of your helper function, something like:

```
yourHelperFunction: function(helper) {
...
var flattened = helper.flattenQueryResult(course);
...
}
```

Comment: It's already in Helper class. That's why I use **this.flattenQueryResult(course);**

Comment: I've just edited my answer